# 2013 Malibu vacuum pump

Tags: chevrolet, oil-leak, malibu

I had a pretty substantial oil leak from behind my vacuum pump. I bought a seal and when I went to change it I found that the part that meets up to the camshaft was just broken into many pieces. I got my magnet fished everything out and went back to the auto parts store and bought a new vacuum pump. Came back home put in the new seal and put in the new pump. As soon as the car started the pump began to leak oil at what looks to be a drain plug on the bottom of the new pump. I took it out again. Took out the drain plug and noticed there is no o-ring or any type of rubber seal down there. I have no idea if this is normal or not. I have another pump that's going to be picked up this morning and I will swap it out. Should some type of sealant be put on that plug and or surrounding metal gasket?

Comment: A photo or two might be helpful.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintnenance & Repair!